# How do I generate application installer in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've developed an application in Android Studio and now I'd like to generate the apk.

I followed some tutorials where I went in Build -> Generate Single Budle ... and a ".jks" file is generated.

Is this file that I should copy to my mobile phone? If so, how?(a message appears saying that the file is not supported).

Comment: you have to choose `APK` instead of  `Android App Bundle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Everything is very simple.**

1. Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK -> Set APK
2. Use your key or create new *this key is your digital signage
3. After Successful build you can find your APK file inside the project folder itself.
   (path: `project_folder/app/release/apk-release.apk`)

> Put attention to digital signature! If you are publishing  your APP in Google Play store, then you should keep that file safely. If you lose your key,then you can't submit any updates to your App. Even nunky from Google can't to do anything. Keep it in a safe place.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]